# LibGDX actor doesn't respond to click event

Tags: java, libgdx, actor

I got a screen class with a stage. In the constructor, I add UIBar and BattleScene to the stage. UIBar draws everything on the UI Bar, and BattleScene draws everything on the battlefield. BattleScene holds an array of CharacterSlots[6]. Each character slot has x and y positions, and actor attached to it.

In my BattleScene draw method, I call the draw methods of each CharacterSlot, and they call the draw method of the actor attached to them.

I got bounds set on my actor like so:

**actor.setBounds(actor.getX(), actor.getY(), actor.getWidth(),actor.getHeight());**

Now, everything gets nicely drawn on the screen, yet actors don't respond to the listener I attached to them in the constructor like so:

```
    this.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("ay");
            currentlyChosen = reference;
            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you remember to set the input processor to the stage? `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);`

Comment: Yes, in a class that is implementing the screen. In its show() method I do just that.

Comment: How do you attach actors to the BattleScene? For them to react automatically, BattleScene needs to be a Group subclass and they need to be added to it as its children.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!